# How to determine if an AWS s3 bucket has at least one public object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's suppose that I have a bucket with many folders and objects.
This bucket has `Objects can be public` as policy access. If I want to know if there is at least one public object or list all public objects, how should I do this? Is there any way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you would need to loop through every object and call `GetObjectAcl()`.

You'd preferably do it in a programming language, but here is an example with the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket my-bucket --key foo.txt

{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "...",
        "ID": "..."
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "...",
                "ID": "...",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "Group",
                "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
        }
    ]
}
```

I granted the `READ` permission by using **Make Public** in the S3 management console. Please note that objects could also be made public via a **Bucket Policy**, which would not show up in the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method from AWS SDK to do this with JavaScript: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property. There is an SDK for every major language like Java etc. Use the one that you know.

````
 var params = {
  Bucket: "examplebucket", 
  MaxKeys: 2
 };
 s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     {
   // bucket isnt empty
   if (data.length != 0)
   console.log(data);           // successful response
   }
   /*
   data = {
    Contents: [
       {
      ETag: "\"70ee1738b6b21e2c8a43f3a5ab0eee71\"", 
      Key: "happyface.jpg", 
      LastModified: <Date Representation>, 
      Size: 11, 
      StorageClass: "STANDARD"
     }, 
       {
      ETag: "\"becf17f89c30367a9a44495d62ed521a-1\"", 
      Key: "test.jpg", 
      LastModified: <Date Representation>, 
      Size: 4192256, 
      StorageClass: "STANDARD"
     }
    ], 
    IsTruncated: true, 
    KeyCount: 2, 
    MaxKeys: 2, 
    Name: "examplebucket", 
    NextContinuationToken: "1w41l63U0xa8q7smH50vCxyTQqdxo69O3EmK28Bi5PcROI4wI/EyIJg==", 
    Prefix: ""
   }
   */
 });```
````

Comment: This answer does not seem to answer the OP's requirements to only locate objects that are publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of John's answer, you might find this helpful:

```
import concurrent.futures

import boto3


BUCKETS = [
    "TODO"
]


def get_num_objs(bucket):
    num_objs = 0

    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    for res in paginator.paginate(
        Bucket=bucket,
    ):
        if "Contents" not in res:
            print(f"""No contents in res={res}""")
            continue
        num_objs += len(res["Contents"])

    return num_objs


for BUCKET in BUCKETS:
    print(f"Analyzing bucket={BUCKET}...")
    num_objs = get_num_objs(BUCKET)
    print(f"BUCKET={BUCKET} has num_objs={num_objs}")
    # if num_objs > 10_000:
    #     raise Exception(f"num_objs={num_objs}")


    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    def assert_no_public_obj(res):
        if res["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] != 200:
            raise Exception(res)
        if "Contents" not in res:
            print(f"""No contents in res={res}""")
            return
        print(f"""Fetched page with {len(res["Contents"])} objs...""")

        for i, obj in enumerate(res["Contents"]):
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print(f"""Fetching {i}-th obj in page...""")
            res = s3_client.get_object_acl(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=obj["Key"])
            for grant in res["Grants"]:
                # Amazon S3 considers a bucket or object ACL public if it grants any permissions to members of the predefined AllUsers or AuthenticatedUsers groups.
                # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html#access-control-block-public-access-policy-status
                uri = grant["Grantee"].get("URI")
                if not uri:
                    continue
                if "AllUsers" in uri or "AuthenticatedUsers" in uri:
                    raise Exception(f"""Grantee={grant["Grantee"]} found for {BUCKET}/{obj["Key"]}""")

    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for res in paginator.paginate(
            Bucket=BUCKET,
        ):
            executor.submit(assert_no_public_obj, res)
```